# other type of checkedlistbox need answer

Tags: vb.net

i'm a new guy to learn vb...in my question to save checkedlistbox to database.
my question is:
LocalDatabase table 1: Employee

**[EMPLOYEE]**

[image]

**Form1**

[image]

**LocalDatabase table 2 : record**

[image]

checkedlistbox list form Employee datatable..then i want save the value to database where checkedlistbox selected...i don't know how to coding vb...can somebody help?? 
i have tried in code by learn in other..but still have in question in checklistbox saving.
my code
vb class

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class ConnectionDatabase
    Public dset As New DataSet
    Public adaptor As New SqlDataAdapter
    Public conn As New SqlConnection
    Public cmd As New SqlCommand
    Public locate As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\asus\Documents\vs twins\TT - Copy\TT\twin.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
End class
```

so in vb coding is:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Record
    Dim vs As New ConnectionDatabase
    Dim tblDIV As DataTable
    Dim daDIV As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dsDIV As New DataSet
    Dim oCon As SqlConnection
    Private Sub Record_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim oCon = New SqlConnection
        oCon.ConnectionString = vs.locate
        dsDIV = New DataSet
        daDIV = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Name FROM Employee", oCon)
        Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(daDIV)
        builder.QuotePrefix = "["
        builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"

        Try
            daDIV.FillSchema(dsDIV, SchemaType.Source, "DIV")
            daDIV.Fill(dsDIV, "DIV")
            tblDIV = dsDIV.Tables("DIV")
            CheckedListBox1.DataSource = tblDIV
            CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Encountered an Error;" & vbNewLine & ex.Message)
            oCon.Close()
        End Try
End Sub
    Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim TextBox1 As Double
        Dim TextBox2 As Double
        Dim Ans As Double

    WkH = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    WkS = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    Ans = WkH * WkS
    Label4.Text = Ans
End Sub
```

that is all can be run...but i can't code in the last part (saving into database) can suggest some link or example to learn ??Please Help Thank You..

Comment: You have to try coding before you'll get help.

Comment: ok...i will try...thank you for reply...